# Which method I should use and why?

Tags: php, mysql

I am establishing a database connection in php using the function

`$DBConn = mysql_connect ("localhost" , "testuser" , "test123")`

At the time of releasing the connection I am using

```
if( is_resource($DBConn) )
```

to check whether the connection is currently set or not. I want to know is it efficient to do this or I should check the connection like this

```
if( $DBConn )
```

I want to know prod and cons of using both the statements.

Comment: If you are writing some fancy new code, consider it a great time to switch from `mysql_*` and move to PDO instead :)

Comment: There is no difference worth mentioning. Use the second option, it's simpler to read.

Comment: @Jon dont u think that there is a function call associated with is_resource() and it may have some overhead in calling a function. Just an opinion.

Comment: @Fluffeh I am just a beginner in php

Comment: @Mayank PDO is the new *safe, shiny and secure* mway to connect to a database, I am just saying that it is a great time to consider switching to a new connection object/functions and writing it so that it uses prepared statements rather than allowing for injection attacks my good sir!

Comment: @Mayank: The overhead may or may not be greater than the boolean test. Whichever of the two is slower is going to be slower by such a small margin that you will never be able to measure it unless you iterate a few million times. But the nature of this test is such that you are only going to do it a couple of times at most. As I said, no difference worth mentioning.

Comment: Agreed with @Fluffeh. Switch to PDO now. The old `mysql_xx()` funcs are considered obsolete -- even the PHP manual recommends not using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should no longer be using `mysql_xxx` functions; there are many articles out there that discuss the benefits of having prepared statements, etc. with PDO / mysqli.

By looking at the manual, it states that it returns a link identifier or `false` on failure. You shouldn't make assumptions as to what exactly this identifier is, it's usually a resource but it may as well be an object or integer. I would simply negate the easier condition:

```
if (false !== $DBConn) {
    // do something with the database
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
if (false === $DBConn) {
    throw new Exception("Could not connect to database");
}
// do something with the database
```

**Edit**

Using `if ($DBConn) { ... }` is okay as well, because it's basically the opposite of 0, false, null, "" and empty array.

Answer (score 0):

A resource identifier is returned upon successful connection or querying. Thus the function `is_resource` will identify a variable as a resource or false.

and if an `If` expression evaluates to `TRUE`, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to `FALSE`, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are essentially the same, though one might argue that called the `is_resource` method has the overhead of calling the function, the `if` also has to determine this and it virtually leaves no difference between both of them. Its all about your style of coding and readability i guess